# Kontorovich Lebedev transform

Tags: analytic-number-theory, special-functions, automorphic-forms, integral-transforms, bessel-functions

By the title I mean [reference: ``Spectral methods of Automorphic forms" by Iwaniec (B.41)-(B.43)] for $f\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R^+})$, one has
$$f(x)=\pi^{-2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty K_{it}(x)F_f(t)t\sinh(\pi t)dt,$$
where $$F_f(t):=\int_0^\infty f(y)K_{it}(y)\frac{dy}{y},$$ and
$K_{it}$ is the $K$-Bessel function of purely imaginary order. I have problem understanding the convergence of the $t$-integral here.

I can see $$F_f(t) \ll_f (1+|t|)^{-n}\cosh(\pi t)^{-1/2},$$ which can be deduced from the definition of $F_f$, by repeated integration by parts and Cauchy-Schwarz afterwards. A usual integral representation of $K_{it}$ is 
$$K_{it}(x)=\frac{(x/2)^{it}\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma(1/2+it)}\int_{1}^\infty e^{-xu}(u^2-1)^{it-1/2}du.$$

From the above $K_{it}\ll_x \cosh(t)^{1/2}$ in the $t$ variable. Clearly this is not sufficient to prove the convergence of the $t$ integral because of $\sinh(\pi t)$ in the integral.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The function $K_{it}(x)$ decreases much faster than $\cosh(t)^{1/2}$. At the moment I don't have time to point you to a reference, but I'm going to do it later.

Comment: Annother observation. Run "plot  BesselK[I*t,1]*exp(Pi*t/2)/Sqrt(t)  for t in range (0,100)" in WolframAlpha to get an idea of how this function behaves.

Comment: It seems decaying. So two $e^{-\pi t/2}$ coming from two $K$-Bessel functions should cancel $\sinh(\pi t).$ Could you give me any explicit bound in $t$, or some reference? Thanks.

Comment: An asymptotic expansion in terms of Airy functions can be deduced by formula (4.12) of "Uniform asymptotic approximations for the Whittaker functions $M_{k,ir}(x)$ and $W_{k,ir}(x)$" (Dunster, 2003) by setting $k=0$. But this is clearly overkilling. Indeed an asymptotic for modified Bessel functions should have been known long before. I can't find any reference though. Please let me know whether you find any!